# How to set the metadata of individual parallel routes in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I have the following structure, i am using parallel routes in NextJS 13:

[image]

in `layout.tsx` i have a conditional to either show `@folder1/page.tsx` or `@folder2/page.tsx` or `@folder3/page.tsx`

that works like it should no issues there, what is not working is the metadata inside each `page.tsx`, i have:

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
     title: 'My title folder 1', // same in the other page.tsx except it says 2 or 3
};
```

When i am loading `folder2` it will always show the metadata from `folder1`, same with `folder3`, am i missing something?